# javascript replace all next text

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this text for example

```
'test test: field test test 1 - pid 20242004 test test test 543 - pid 20242004 test test test 123 - pid 544745456 test test jdfh 1 - pid 353545 test test test 1 - pid 20242004 test test test 6 - pid 878 field test test 23 - pid 234445'
```

and I want to change all the text next the word 'pid' so the output will be:

```
'test test: field test test 1 - pid <a>20242004</a> test test test 543 - pid <a>20242004</a> test test test 123 - pid <a>544745456</a> test test jdfh 1 - pid <a>353545</a> test test test 1 - pid <a>20242004</a> test test test 6 - pid <a>878</a> field test test 23 - pid <a>234445</a>'
```

is there any way to do that with javascript?

Comment: Yes, that's possible with JavaScript

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), try to solve the issue by yourself and then come back if you need further help (see ["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with regular expressions

in this expression i try to fetch any string that has the word `pid` and after it it has chunk of digits

```js
let str = 'test test: field test test 1 - pid 20242004 test test test 543 - pid 20242004 test test test 123 - pid 544745456 test test jdfh 1 - pid 353545 test test test 1 - pid 20242004 test test test 6 - pid 878 field test test 23 - pid 234445'

let newStr = str.replace(/pid ([\d]+)/g, `pid <a>$1</a>`)

console.log(newStr)
```

for more info about `replace` check [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/replace)